# How to store wordpress media in google cloud storage

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-storage

I have a Linode server running a wordpress site, the media in /wp-content/uploads its getting big and filling up my server SSD drive. So I want to move it to Google Cloud Storage.

I have checkout WP2CLOUD but requires ClouSE wich does not support MySQL server 5.1.73-1. Im running Debian with linux 2.6.32-5-amd64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to upload WordPress media files into Google Cloud Storage, install the [**WP-Stateless** plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/). It's free and I run it across all my client WordPress websites.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [WP2Cloud](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp2cloud-wordpress-to-cloud) (WordPress plugin) may be a perfect solution for you. 
It allows you to either

- Take the whole website data to cloud storage.
- Only upload media files to cloud storage.
- Only migrate website content to cloud storage while store media files in uploads folder on Web server running WordPress.

Supports both Amazon S3 and Google Cloud Storage

Comment: WP2Cloud doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to create a bucket `ex. cloud.my-domain.com`.

---

Get [Google Client PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

There are plenty of examples already in there for how to authenticate.

### Wordpress

```
// Run this function on every image upload

add_action('wp_handle_upload', 'process_images');
function process_images($results) {

   if( $results['type'] === 'image/jpeg' || $results['type'] === 'image/png' || $results['type'] === 'image/gif' ) {
       $imgfilename = $results[ 'file' ];
       $imgurl = $results[ 'url' ];

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $theme_image ) ) {
          $imageName = wp_basename($imgurl);
          // Save image to cloud storage
          saveToStorage($imgurl, $imageName, $results['type']);
        }

       return $results;
  }
}

function saveToStorage($url, $imageName, $type){
    $objects = callGoogleClient(); 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $imgData = curl_exec($ch);

    $postbody = array('mimeType' => $type, "data" => $imgData);
    $gso = new Google_StorageObject();
    $gso->setName(A_CLOUD_FOLDER.'/'.$imageName);
    $resp = $objects->insert(MY_BUCKET, $gso, $postbody);
}

// Delete an image from cloud storage
add_filter('wp_delete_file', 'on_remove_file');
function on_remove_file($file) {
    $objects = callGoogleClient();
    $name = wp_basename($file);
    $resp = $objects->delete(MY_BUCKET, A_CLOUD_FOLDER.'/'. $name);
  return $file;
}


function callGoogleClient(){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('your_id.apps.googleusercontent.com');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, KEY_FILE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $key = curl_exec($ch);

    $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
      array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'),
      $key)
    );

    $StorageService = new Google_StorageService($client);
    $objects = $StorageService->objects;

    return $objects;
}
```

---

I have disabled the option `Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders` therefore right after an image is uploaded to the storage the wp-upload get's cleared on every upload.